# Want to publish vue nuxt.js app to iis on windows server

Tags: vue.js, iis, nuxt.js

maybe someone more experienced in IIS could help.
I have the following scenario: Windows Server 2019, mais site and several applications running on IIS 10 i.e (site.com/app1, site.com/app2).
My objective is to have a vue/nuxt app running in site.com/app3, utilizing same SSL config.

I've already tested IISNode and Url Rewrite without success, my best shot was redirecting site.com/app3 to port 3000 where the app is running, but it doesn't load anything but the main page.

Comment: Do you use Nuxt as SPA-only, SSR, or SSG? Why specifically a Windows server?

Comment: SSR, the application will consume an API in the same server. My environment is all Windows on premise.

Comment: I'm not familiar with IIS, maybe give it a try to [that one](https://nuxtjs.org/deployments) if there is something similar there. Otherwise: what have you tried so far? There are no articles on that topic?

Comment: I've already tested IISNode and Url Rewrite without success, my best shot was redirecting site.com/app3 to port 3000 where the app is running, but it doesn't load anything but the main page.
I've seen some old (2y) YT videos, tried some other "hackish" ways, but no sucess

Comment: About deploy vue nuxt.js app to IIS. You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59914489/how-to-deploy-nuxt-with-iis). I see that you have tested IISNode and Url Rewrite but without success. You can use [FRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing) to generate failure logs. Locate the cause based on logs.

Comment: hey @TengFeiXie thanks for your reply. The solution proposed in the article was one of the first shots I gave. See its a 2 years old article. Last IISNode version dates from 2017. There must be something newer, some straight forward approach.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nuxtjs If you can get your Nuxt app first running as a new site, then you can dig further on how to move it to an IIS application under a site.

Comment: @LexLi proposed solution actually worked for me. I had to tweak a little to make it work as a subfolder from my main site (mydomain.com/myapp)

Comment: Then you can post/accept your own answer below.